# R: object 'latexrms' not found

Tags: r

I want to use function latexrms() but I can not. rms package is installed and a `?latexrms` works.

But `str(latexrms)` gives following error and any other use of this function produces an error too.

> Error in str(latexrms) : object 'latexrms' not found

Comment: You've probably over-written it. Close your R session and re-open it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg ; i think it might be something else... beyond my ken .. after `library(rms)`, `?latexrms` retuns the help page, but `latexrms` returns not found, and to see the code it seems `rms:::latexrms` has to be used. Seems something about how the function is exported (nothing in `methods(latex)`). EDIT: seems like latexrms is an internal function, so no need to call it directly.

Comment: `rms:::latexrms()` works. Thanks